# Autowiring in validator

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I use my own validator class and mark it with @Autowired -anotation in my controller. I also have to use database and ldap connections, so I autowire them too in the same controller constructor.

My validator must use database and ldap connections too, so I'd have to autowire database and ldap in its constructor. It is double autowiring indeed! But now my problem is how can I get the database and ldap work in validator? With no wiring, they return null. Any help?

This is a continuence to my earlier question about autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a real question in here. Read these parts of the Spring Reference:

- [Autowiring Collaborators](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire)
- [`@Autowired` and `@Inject`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Are the autowires actually doing what you expect them to do? Alternatively you can explicitely inject your dependencies to be sure.

Comment: The database bean accomplishes the connection to database, and ldap bean to ldap.

Answer (score 0):

The @Autowire in the Controller is wiring validator to the controller.You need to add @Autowire in Validator as well to wire ldap and database beans. Please also add your code and configuration in your question so that we can understand it better.